# How to communicate with VM from host when no internet connection is available

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, web-development, webstorm

I have a Centos 7 VM that I am setting up for webapp development.  The host is windows 10 Pro.  WebStorm, MySQL Workbench, and FileZilla are my host-based workhorses for remote management and development.

To clarify the question: How should my Hyper-V settings (VM settings, Virtual Switch Manager, etc.), and CentOS settings (NetworkManager, ifcfg files, SELinux, etc.) be configured to allow easy switching between my physical network devices/interfaces (Ethernet/WiFi) and a "non-connected" situation.

Let me explain my current setup:  I have a Hyper-V Virtual Switch setup that uses External network to connect to.  When I move from Ethernet to WiFi (or visa versa) I have to go into Virtual Switch Manager and change the External network from/to Ethernet/WiFi.  I have a desktop shortcut to open the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) where I manualy edit the ip address that is reported on the VM using `ip a`.  This works really great for me, when I have a physical connection to a network.  I am able to ssh in and use my other tools to develop with ease.

But, if I'm not able to connect to a network, I'm at a loss.  I'm assuming that it is because the host is unable to provide DNS.  I could be very wrong, I'm a SysAdmin aprentice, but networking noob.

So my real question (in more completely fleshed-out form) becomes, how can I use my 'connected' workflow and tools when I'm in a non-connected state?

I'm open to all possibilities ...  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a internal virtual switch .

Then configure IP address (assume it is 192.168.1.100) for the virtual NIC (by default , it's name should be vEthernet(***VirtualSwithName***) ).

Also , configure IP address for that VM (assume it is 192.168.1.101) .

Edit your HOSTS file .